# Defining Functions In Relation To Other Functions Without Considering Implementation Details

Tags: haskell

I have written a function called 'oddOf' that correctly determines whether or not a given value has an odd number of presences in a list. It is defined like so:

```
oddOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
oddOf value list = oddOf' value list False
    where oddOf' val (x:xs) acc = if x == val
                                  then oddOf' val xs (not acc)
                                  else oddOf' val xs acc
          oddOf'  _     _   acc = acc
```

I would like to write a function that determines whether or not a given value has an even number of presences in a list. When presented with binary choices such as these, it is the best practice to implement one and define the other as 'not its complement'. With that in mind, I tried out the definition:

```
evenOf = not oddOf
```

To me, that looks like a reasonable partially-applied function, but it is not valid Haskell code. What is it about the language that I need to understand better? What is the elegant way to define evenOf that I am looking for?

Comment: Another nice way is to move `oddOf'` to the top level (don't export it, probably), change the argument order (and name), `fooOf :: (Eq a) => Bool -> a -> [a] -> Bool`, and have `oddOf = fooOf False` and `evenOf = fooOf True`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's good practice to be thinking about code reuse this way, and I'll get to that, but first:

**Using function composition to write more neatly**

Can I first point out as an aside that I would define your `oddOf` function more simply using existing functions:

```
oddOf :: Eq a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
oddOf value list = odd . length . filter (== value) $ list
```

`f $ x = f x` but has low precedence, so that's a neater way of writing `(not . even . length . filter (== value) ) list`.

This works by composing functions; we take the list and filter it so we get just the ones that equal the `value`, using partial application of `(==)` in the form of an 'operator section' `(== value) :: Eq a => a -> Bool`. Next we  find the `length` of that, check if it's `even`, then finally negate the answer with `not`. This hints at a concise way of writing `evenOf`:

```
evenOf :: Eq a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
evenOf value list = even . length . filter (== value) $ list
```

In fact, since the prelude defines `odd` as `not . even` it would be very slightly simpler to start with `evenOf` and define `oddOf` from that.

**Why `not . oddOf` isn't what you wanted**

Looking at types, you have

```
not :: Bool -> Bool
oddOf :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
(.) :: (b -> bb) -> (a -> b) -> a -> bb  -- function composition
```

Now `->` associates to the right, which means that really,

```
oddOf :: Eq a => a -> ([a] -> Bool)
```

Secretly, that means that Haskell functions only ever take one argument! (What we think of as functions that take more than one argument are actually functions that take one argument then return a function that'll take another, etc...) Unfortunately that means we can't match the types up with `(.)` directly, because we'd need `b` to be `Bool`, not `[a] -> Bool`.

### Simple solutions to your problem

OK, sorry I took a while to get to the answer you wanted, but I think that was all worth saying.

- **Simple solution 1** is writing `evenOf` with function composition as I showed you above.

  ```
  oddOf  value list =  odd . length . filter (== value) $ list
  evenOf value list = even . length . filter (== value) $ list
  ```
- **Simple solution 2** is writing `evenOf` directly from `oddOf` by supplying all the arguments:

  ```
  evenOf value list = not $ oddOf value list
  oddOf  value list = odd . length . filter (== value) $ list
  ```
- **Simple solution 3** is writing `evenOf value` by composing `not` with `oddOf value`

  The only problem with `not.oddOf` was that `oddOf` doesn't return a `Bool` directly, it returns a `[a]->Bool`. We can fix this by supplying one of the arguments. Notice that `oddOf value` has type `Eq a => [a] -> Bool` so we *can* compose that with `not`, because it *does* return a `Bool`:

  ```
  evenOf value      = not . oddOf value
  oddOf  value list = odd . length . filter (== value) $ list
  ```
- **Simple solution 4** is putting together simple solutions 1 and 2 to write `oddOf` using `evenOf` instead:

  ```
  oddOf  value list = not $ evenOf value list
  evenOf value list = even . length . filter (== value) $ list
  ```

  (You could, of course, do the same thing to simple solutions 1 and 3.)

## Awesome brain-changing ways to solve the problem

Every Haskell programmer should read Conal Elliott's excellent [semantic editor combinators webpage/article](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators).

In particular, you should read it since it answers your question title "Defining Functions In Relation To Other Functions Without Considering Implementation Details" in a very general way; "Semantic Editor Combinators" is Conal's phrase for exactly that concept.

The main idea is that you can edit a function after it's written by writing a sort of path to the value you want to change in brackets, the function you want to apply at that point, then the original function. In this case, you need to apply `not` to the result (`::Bool`) of the result (`::Eq a => [a]->Bool`) of the original function (`:: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`).

So if you want to edit the result of the result with `not`, you do:

```
oddOf = (result.result) not evenOf
evenOf value list = even . length . filter (== value) $ list
```

Conal Elliott defines `result = (.)` because it's conceptually easier, but you could define

```
oddOf = ((.).(.)) not evenOf
evenOf value list = even . length . filter (== value) $ list
```

directly if you prefer.

If you needed to change `more :: a -> b -> [a] -> [b] -> Bool`, you could use

```
less = (result.result.result.result) not more
```

or

```
less = ((.).(.).(.).(.)) not more
```

Using the same idea, you can change inside a list, part of a pair, one of the arguments,...
Read the paper for a deeper and fuller explanation.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `odd` instead of `not . even` in the first place?

Comment: @MikeHartl Doh! Yes! Edited - thanks. In fact the prelude defines `odd = not.even`, so I still prefer doing `even` first, and the mathematician in me feels calmer as a result. :)

Answer (score 8):

I'm afraid that `not oddOf` isn't a reasonable partially-applied function. It's an application of `not` to `oddOf`.

`not` has type `Bool -> Bool`; it takes a single `Bool` argument and returns a `Bool`. `oddOf` isn't a `Bool`, so `not` can't be applied to it. But what you want is not to apply `not` to `oddOf` itself, but to apply `not` to the *result* of applying `oddOf` to two arguments.

The most direct way to do what you want is to write something like this:

```
evenOf value list = not $ oddOf value list
```

This is theoretically a little less direct and abstract than it could be, because rather than just defining `evenOf` by its relationship to `oddOf` directly you're "manually" wiring up the inputs to `evenOf` to the inputs of `oddOf` and then post-processing its result. A point-free version, such as Ziyao Wei's suggested:

```
evenOf = ((not .) .) oddOf
```

more directly states that relationship, freeing the reader from having to verify that the 2 arguments to `evenOf` are simply passed to `oddOf` in the same order and not used for any other purpose. But generally it takes quite a deep familiarity with Haskell to find that version clearer (otherwise you have to instead verify what exactly the nested composition sections do to see the "directly stated" relationship). So if you're more comfortable with explicitly naming and "wiring" the arguments, that's probably the elegant way you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is actually calling the `not` function with `oddOf` as parameter. The `(.)` function is used to compose 2 functions but only when you have binary functions i.e functions that take a single parameter and return a value, which ofcourse is not the case with `oddOf` because it is `a -> [a] -> Bool`.

We can make oddOf a binary function if we can make it `(a, [a]) -> Bool`. This can be done using `uncurry`. The other function called `curry` does the opposite i.e it will make `(a,[a])  -> Bool` back to `a -> [a] -> Bool`.

We can use these `curry` `uncurry` functions to achieve what we want:

```
evenOf :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
evenOf = curry $ not . (uncurry oddOf)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other options, and to help you understand what's going on, recognize that if you use a tuple for your oddOf arguments, it *will* work.

```
let oddOf (value, list) = ...
let evenOf = not . oddOf
```

This is because oddOf is now a function that returns a Bool.  With untupled arguments, then it's a function that returns a function that returns a Bool, which is different.

So now `not oddOf` still doesn't work because we're not partially applying here--`not` is `Bool -> Bool`; there *is* no partial application possible there.  Instead we're going back to the old mathematical function *composition*—f(g(x)) -> (f.g)(x).  Here `g` is `oddOf` and `f` is `not`.  Then the Haskell representation is as above.

The basic premise of your problem all comes down to my second paragraph—you've got a function that returns a *function*.  All the answers here present some way of converting that into a function that returns a *Bool*, and then doing function composition with `not`.  Try reading the answers all in that light and it should give you a better understanding.  In particular look at AndrewC's simple solution #3 with this in mind.